# XPath behaviour with conflicting XML namespace prefixes

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath

Consider the following XML:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<movies xmlns:en="http://english-language.com/">
    <en:movie>
        <title>The Godfather</title>
    </en:movie>
    <en:movie>
        <title>Saving Private Ryan</title>
    </en:movie>
    <something-something xmlns:en="http://english.com/">
        <en:movie>
            <title>The Fellowship of the Ring</title>
        </en:movie>
    </something-something>
</movies>
```

This code below will match **The Godfather** and **Saving Private Ryan**. But why? I expected it to fail.  It seems that the query ignores the namespace name (URI) in favor of the namespace prefix

```php
$xpath      = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('en', 'http://complete-nonsense');
$elements   = $xpath->query("//en:movie");
```

I expected the code below to match **The Fellowship of the Ring**, but again it matches **The Godfather** and **Saving Private Ryan**.

```php
$xpath      = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('en', 'http://english.com/');
$elements   = $xpath->query("//en:movie");
```

Only now the does the URI seem to make any difference, now it matches the **The Fellowship of the Ring**.

```php
$xpath      = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('english', 'http://english.com/');
$elements   = $xpath->query("//english:movie");
```

Why is that? Is it something wrong with PHP's implementation or what?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27816050/simplexml-and-xpath-read-sibling/27816518?noredirect=1#comment44068542_27816518, this particular implementation might redeclare namespaces with the prefixes found in the input document, for convenience.

Comment: Thank you @MathiasMüller. This seems... odd... I hope to never come across a document composed of multiple xml trees that so happens to share a prefix or two. That would be annoying

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DOMXpath::evaluate()`/`DOMXpath::query()` register the namespace definitions of the current context node on top of the manually registered ones. Basically the document will override the namespace for a prefix. The third argument (since PHP >= 5.3.3) can disable the automatic registration:

```
$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXML($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);
$xpath->registerNamespace('en', 'http://english.com/');

// the xmlns:en from the document element overrides the registration
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(//en:movie)'));
// automatic registration disabled - works correctly
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('normalize-space(//en:movie)', NULL, FALSE));
```

Output:

```
string(13) "The Godfather"
string(26) "The Fellowship of the Ring"
```